# I do not understand the length of the cache list

Tags: ipython

in picture below. Can somebody tell me why the length is 4?
I would expect a length of 3 (because of 3 arrays) but I don't know where the 4 is coming from?

```
A, W, b = linear_forward_test_case()

Z, linear_cache = linear_forward(A, W, b)

caches.append(linear_cache)

print("Z = " + str(Z))

print("cache =" + str(linear_cache))
print("Length of caches list = " + str(len(caches)))
```

Outcome

```
Z = [[ 3.26295337 -1.23429987]]
cache =(array([[ 1.62434536, -0.61175641],
       [-0.52817175, -1.07296862],
       [ 0.86540763, -2.3015387 ]]), array([[ 1.74481176, -0.7612069 ,  0.3190391 ]]), array([[-0.24937038]]))
Length of caches list = 4
```

[image: Length of the cache list]

Comment: Please paste the code as text and not as a picture - it would make it much easier to read.

Comment: what is the return type of `linear_forward`?

Comment: I don't know. I took a simpler exampler now and do not understand why the length is 5. Here I would expect 2. Here my code 'def sum(a,b):
    c = a+b
    d = a+2*b
    cache = a,b
    return c,d,cache

c,d,cache = sum(2,4)
caches.append(cache)

print(d)
print(cache)
print(len(caches))' and here the outcome: 10
(2, 4)
5

Comment: PS: I don't know how to put code in a comment :-(